# AWS CloudSearch Filter on non-indexed field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to do a structured query with a lot of dynamic fields (potentially) in the search pattern. So far everything is good, except I want to be able to limit from the result by field that is not indexed. Is this possible?

The test search console is showing this error: `"Syntax Error in query: field (fieldname) is not searchable"`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I want to be able to limit from the result by field that is not indexed" and maybe include an example with the desired behavior?

Comment: @alexroussos http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/filtering-results.html describes how to use filters. Filters are what I want to be able to use, but I can't use them on a non-indexed field (that exists).

Comment: Now I get it. Yeah I think @nanestev is right

Comment: @alexroussos I ended up indexing it anyways as a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All index fields that you intend to use for filtering should be marked as searchable:

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to filter a field that isn't indexed?

Comment: @hkf do you have specific concerns around indexing more fields? You're allowed up to 200 indexed fields* so unless you're bumping up against that, you should be ok. I've never used dynamic fields but it sounds like you configure them the same as static ones. *http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: @alexroussos not specifically but we do not want to pay for a feature/storage that we're not going to use.

Comment: I don't think count if searchable fields reflects pricing. It only depends on instance type and count. You also pay for uploading documents and when indexing the search domain, but it's just a fraction of the total price.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by checking out the Cloudsearch console network payload.

If you are filtering by a facet field that is not marked searchable, you have to add a second query parameter: `fq=<facetFieldName>&facet.<facetFieldName>={}`. This seems to filter the results as expected.